# Why wasn't this character completely eaten by the zombies

Tags: the-walking-dead

When watching how the zombies behave - they just overwhelm their victim and then start devouring it.

However when

> Sophia gets turned into a zombie she gets just bitten and then becomes a zombie. 
>  Why didn't the zombie just eat her or inflict more severe wounds?

(I'm making this a spoiler-alert because honestly this is one of the most horrifying scenes in the series ... at least for me)

Comment: Is there anyone in The Walking Dead TV universe that we know for sure has been *completely* eaten?

Comment: Lori was completely eaten was she not?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We never saw the attack happen, so any answer is going to be speculative.  However, we do know that she was bit on the shoulder, which unlike an arm or a leg doesn't necessarily require a significant grip to attack (particularly if striking from behind).  It's easy to imagine that a lone zombie got her on the shoulder, she instinctively squirmed away at that first contact and ran, maybe got away from it long enough for it to be distracted by someone else or forget she existed, and then died on her own and became a zombie.